# Calling in-line model variable substitution in python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder

For the model results in Model Builder, I am writing a python script tool which would write the results into a simple text (.txt) file. The problem I am encountering is that I do not know how to call the in-line model variable substitutions in a python script code. I have a few in-line model variables that I need to use for the results writing, for example, one comes from the Parse Path tool as a "Name_DBF". In code it is defined as route_name. How to complete the code correctly as I am getting syntax errors?

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys

workspace = r'C:\Users\Aura\Desktop\Andriui'

input_table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

route_name = %Name_DBF%

dvir_tipas = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# this is how you create a file in Python
file = open('C:\Users\Aura\Desktop\Andriui\RouteDesc.txt','w')
# create a row object to navigate your table
rows = ap.SearchCursor(input_table) 
row = rows.next()
# for each row in your table, retrieve the value in the 'XXX' field, convert it 
# to a string, write it to your output file, then move to the next line in both 
# your input table and output file for row in rows:
file.write("Maršruto pavadinimas:" + str(route_name) + '\n')
file.write("Maršruto atstumas:" + " " + str(row.Atstumas_M) + " " + "km" + '\n')
file.write("Maršruto reljefo sąskaida:" + " " + str(row.Reljefo_S) + " " + "%" + '\n')
file.write("Maršruto sudėtingumas balais nuo 1 iki 3, kai 1 - lengvas, 3 - sunkus maršrutas" + " " + "-" + " " + str(row.Suapvalint) + '\n')
file.write("Apskaičiuota dviratininko tipui: " + " " + str(dvir_tipas) + " " )
del row, rows
file.close()

print "table field data successfully written into file"
```

[image: Script tool at the end of model]

Comment: I suspect that you can use a Calculate Value tool to take an inline variable and return a string to Python.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do in your script is to enclose the inline substitution in quotes.

I created this simple model:

[image: Model]

The script code is simply this:

```py
import arcpy
inlyr = "%Name_DBF%"
out = r"c:\scratch\test.shp"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inlyr,out)
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0,out)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I tried to enclose it the same as you did, but when I open my text file, it only says "%Name_DBF%" in that place, but not a real name of the database table... this is what I was wondering whether in scripting we need to use something more differently than in simple calculate field... but i need to use the script tool as it is easier for me to include more lines of text.

Comment: Interesting, the above works because it is used in a tool (CopyFeatures). If used in some standard python code, like write to text file as you have done it writes %Name_DBF%. The only way I  go the name to pass into the script was to expose a new parameter to your script tool that took a string and got a handle on that using `aText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)`. Then writing to the text file worked as expected.